# JAXB binding - How to define the DomHandler to be used in @XmlAnyElement

Tags: dom, binding, stream, jaxb, any

I have been looking for a way to change the JAXB behavior for xs:any elements, because we are using a stream instead of DOM. We need to be able to handle huge (gigabytes) data files/streams.

JAXB will generate the any-properties using the @XmlAnyElement annotation on them. Since we are using our own stream implementation, we need to avoid JAXB generating the any-property at all. However as it seems it is impossible to tell the JAXB binding to ignore xs:any elements.

At my current research on this topic, I figured out, that one could write a DomHandler, which will be used. Now if this DomHandler would look like this:

```
StreamHandler implements DomHandler<MyStream, StreamResult>
```

we could use this DomHandler to do the job without the need to add the stream logic next to our generated classes. Now we can just reuse the generated any-property for that.

The DomHandler should be set as follows

```
@XmlAnyElement(StreamHandler.class)
```

But how can I define in the jaxb binding xjb-file to use this DomHandler in the generated @XmlAnyElement annotations?

**Edit:**

I filed this [request](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-891) and implemented a JAXB maven-plugin addon to solve this issue. I may request this addon to be added to the basics-addon bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is really the right approach to solve your issue.

What you actually want is to make XJC "ignore" some of the properties when binding. I don't think it is possible at the moment, but it can be solved with a JAXB plugin. Please [file a request](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Issue+tracking).

Now, back to your approach and your question. There is no "native" customization to customize the DOM handler for `@XmlAnyElement`, but you can use the [Annotate Plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin) to add/modify arbitrary annotations in you generated classes. Here is a test project which demonstrates this functionality:

https://svn.java.net/svn/jaxb2-commons~svn/basics/trunk/tests/annotate/

I.e. this customization makes adds `required = true` to the generated `@XmlAttribute` annotation:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='issueJIIB39CType']/xs:attribute[@name='test']">
    <annox:annotate target="field">
        <annox:annotate
            annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute"
            required="false"/>
    </annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

You can do the same thing with `@XmlAnyElement` wll be something like:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="...">
    <annox:annotate target="field">
        <annox:annotate
            annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement"
            value="com.acme.foo.StreamHandler"/>
    </annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem with your proposal is, that using a StreamHandler implements DomHandler<T1, T2> will also require a change of the type of the property. The type of the any property would be T1 now. The signatures of the getter and setter methods should be adjusted as well and the annotation plugin cannot do this job.